# xml reader in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlreader

I want to read the following xml file format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<WIDECAST_DVB>
  <channel name="XXX">
    <event id="0" start_time="2015-01-27 14:00:00" duration="28800">
      <short_event_descriptor lang="alb" name="Edicion informativ">Lajme nga vendi dhe bota</short_event_descriptor>
      <extended_event_descriptor lang="alb">
        <text />
      </extended_event_descriptor>
    </event>
    <event id="1" start_time="2015-01-27 22:00:00" duration="28800">
      <short_event_descriptor lang="alb" name="Edicion informativ">Lajme nga vendi dhe bota</short_event_descriptor>
      <extended_event_descriptor lang="alb">
        <text>jchdvdgd 
        </text>
      </extended_event_descriptor>
    </event>
    <event id="2" start_time="2015-01-28 06:00:00" duration="28800">
      <short_event_descriptor lang="alb" name="Edicion informativ">Lajme nga vendi dhe bota</short_event_descriptor>
      <extended_event_descriptor lang="alb">
        <text />
      </extended_event_descriptor>
    </event>
    <event id="3" start_time="2015-01-28 14:00:00" duration="28800">
      <short_event_descriptor lang="alb" name="Edicion informativ">Lajme nga vendi dhe bota</short_event_descriptor>
      <extended_event_descriptor lang="alb">
        <text />
      </extended_event_descriptor>
    </event>
 </channel>
</WIDECAST_DVB>
```

I want to read this fields:

name, 
start_time, 
duration, 
short event descriptor_name, 
short event description (text within tags), 
extended_event_descriptor/text (text within text tag)

my class is:

```
 public class epg2
    {
        public epg2()
        {
            EventNumber = new List<Event>();
        }
        virtual public string channelname { get; set; }
        virtual public List<Event> EventNumber { get; set; }
        virtual public int number { get; set; }

    }
    public class Event
    {
        public Event()
        {

        }
        virtual public DateTime starttime { get; set; }
        virtual public int duration { get; set; }
        virtual public string name { get; set; }
        virtual public string shortDescription { get; set; }
        virtual public string longDescription { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: You posted an XML but not a single line of code!? Have you tried to read it? For more info, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752796/how-to-read-xml-in-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LinqToXML for example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var resultChannels =
            doc.Descendants("channel")
                .Select(
                        c =>
                            new epg2()
                            {
                                channelname = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                                EventNumber =
                                    c.Elements("event")
                                    .Select(e =>
                                    new Event()
                                    {
                                        name = e.Element("short_event_descriptor").Attribute("name").Value,
                                        starttime = DateTime.Parse(e.Attribute("start_time").Value),
                                        duration = int.Parse(e.Attribute("duration").Value),
                                        shortDescription = e.Element("short_event_descriptor").Value,
                                        longDescription = e.Element("extended_event_descriptor").Element("text").Value
                                    }).ToList()
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: i dont want the results to be array elements

Comment: you can iterate over this array(foreach) and get it one by one or you just do foreach(var item in doc.Descendants("event")) and get the values like in the annonymous type ininitializer

Comment: Its just one possiblility how to be able to do it.

Comment: Added example with foreach

Comment: No clue what the number in epg2 should be mapped to though

Comment: how can i use elements of  c or e??

Comment: what do you mean by how can i use elements of c or e?

Comment: resultchannels should be a list of egp2 objects

Comment: its lamda syntax and points to an element of channel (c) or event (e)