# how to control duplicacy in kml file

Tags: c#

I want to add screen-overlay  in exsisting kml using c#.i have two kml file i  merging them when i am going to do so new file contains two  and  tag is there any way to control this  duplicacy ? or there any other way to add  screen-overlay  in exsisting kml using c#.               thanks in advance..to merge  i am using -

```
    FStream1 = File.Open(sFile1, FileMode.Open);
    FStream2 = File.Open(sFile2, FileMode.Open);
    FStream3 = File.Open(sFile3, FileMode.Append);

    byte[] FStream1Content = new byte[FStream1.Length];
    byte[] FStream2Content = new byte[FStream2.Length];
    FStream1.Read(FStream1Content, 0, (int)FStream1.Length);
    FStream2.Read(FStream2Content, 0, (int)FStream2.Length);

    FStream3.Write(FStream1Content, 0, (int)FStream1.Length);
    FStream3.Write(FStream2Content, 0, (int)FStream2.Length);
```

Comment: This is not *merging*, but a simple concatenation. [KML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) looks like XML to me, you can [read xml](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4752796/1997232)s and then do merging while removing duplicates.

Comment: thanks Sinatr . i tried this but here another problem that my xml has document tag and i want to add new tag inside it but my new tag is creating after closing documet tag. i tried                                                        XmlNode menu = doc.SelectSingleNode("Document");                                   XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ScreenOverlay", null);                                                                               menu.AppendChild(node);  but its giving error

Comment: Sounds like a **new question**. Make sure to include code and error message as well as ask good question (check google first if this question was asked already 100500 times).