# How to Convert <Result>&lt;0.05</Result> into byte array

Tags: c#, encoding

```
byte[] Content = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),Encoding.UTF8, fileAttachment.Content);
fileArray.Add(fileAttachment.Name, Content);
```

I need to get the values from the XML <0.05 in the XML. But while converting the bytearray it's returning null values.

Sample XML given below.

```
<TestMethod Variant="Ash Calculated DMA" Name="INT 1004">
  <TestParameter Name="Ash">
    <Result>&lt;0.01</Result>
    <Unit>% (m/m)</Unit>
    <SpecReport Name="Ash" SpecName="DMA 2005">
      <GroupCondition>Spec Met</GroupCondition>
    </SpecReport>
    <SpecReport Name="Ash" SpecName="DMA 2012">
      <GroupCondition>Spec Met</GroupCondition>
    </SpecReport>
  </TestParameter>
</TestMethod>
```

Comment: can you please add xml tag or sample of your xml tag

Comment: possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752796/how-to-read-xml-in-net

Comment: I am not able to add the XML

Comment: Indent it 4 spaces, as code. Use backticks, ` for inline code (put one on either side). If you click edit now you can see what I did. I added an empty line above the xml and added 4 spaces in front.

Comment: Than you Done from my end. Can you please guide me we need the Result Values "<0.01" while converting into bytearray. But while converting into bytearray we are getting Empty node

Comment: Are you able to show more of your code, please? How are you getting the contents of the XML file into `fileAttachment.Content` (which is presumably an ISO-8859-1 encoded `byte[]`)? What happens next to the UTF-8 encoded `Content` you put into the `fileArray` dictionary?