# How to read a XML value after an attribute

Tags: xml, vb.net

Here is probably a simple question that I just haven been able to find an answer for.

How do I read the value in the value tags in VB.net?

Its from an App.config file. But from a dirrent program. So, I can’t use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Debug")

```
    <applicationSettings>
        <MKA_Service.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="Debug" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ConfigString" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Server=Servername</value>
            </setting>
        </MKA_Service.My.MySettings>
    </applicationSettings>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look at this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752796/how-to-read-xml-in-net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Read XML in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752796/how-to-read-xml-in-net)

Comment: That link gives me the value of the name attribute in setting. Not the value note after